# function: why are all children updating in this backbone collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections

I have a Backbone collectionView that holds x amount of companies.
I also have a collection of x amount of products.

I want to get a random product and add it to a list of "assets" on a random company.  (the company is returned from the `this.getRandomCompany()` function)

But when I run the following function all companies children get updated with the same products all at once.

the result of `console.log(randomCompany)` is a single child, so why are all children updating?

```
   addProduct: function() {
        var randomProductIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * (this.products.length));
        var randomProduct = new App.CompanyModule.Product({
            "name": this.products[randomProductIndex]
        });

        this.getRandomCompany(_.bind(function(randomCompany) {
            console.log(randomCompany);
            randomCompany.model.get("assets").add(randomProduct);
            this.render();
        }, this));
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is your Company model defining the assets property? If it's defined as a direct property of the model or in a defaults *object*, then you'll get the behavior you're describing. If that's the case, move it to a defaults *method*, e.g.

```
var Company = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ...
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            assets: []
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Apologies I dont know why the codeblock is not formatting.  But you are right, my model is the problem, I'm defining it like so        `CompanyModule.Company = Backbone.Model.extend({  
        defaults: {  
            name: "Not specified",  
            status: "private",  
            assets: new CompanyModule.Products()  
        }  
    });`    Thanks for the help!